# Changing highlighColor default option AJAX - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, ajax

I changed the highlightColor and highlightEndColor in the /public/javascript/controls.js file but it isn't changing when the AJAX effect runs. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did those effects work in your view *before* you modified them? If not... to elaborate on EmFi's answer, you should have something like this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

or:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'controls.js' %>
```

These snippets should be somewhere in your application.html.erb usually at the top of the file (in the `<head>`). The application.html.erb is usually found w/in your views/layouts directory.

Comment: They did work. It would flash yellow and I was trying to change that. I only have the :defaults link in the head not the "controls.js'.

Answer (score 0):

Is this file being loaded?

It gets loaded if your view at any point provides :defaults, or "controls.js" to javascript_include_tag. This is usually done in the application layout.